# How to identify shot boundary of a video using a threshold value in python opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I want to implement code for shot boundary detection. The difference measure is the sum of the absolute bin-wise histogram differences. A shot boundary is
declared if the histogram difference between consecutive frames exceeds a threshold.

But i was unable to implement it.
It would be great if anyone can help me on this.

Comment: Please read this forums help section about how to ask a good question and what are appropriate questions. Your question is too broad and you have not shown any code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use cv2.calHist:

```
hist = cv2.calcHist([img],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
```

to calculate the histograms to the current and previous frames

Since the histograms are of the same size, you can take the absolute value of the difference(numpy.abs()), and then take the sum (np.sum()) to calculate the difference measure.

Caution: in practice, it takes a lot of experimenting to come up with the right bin count and the threshold for shot detection.

Comment: yep.still i couldn't find a proper threshold value for boundary detection.

Comment: how can i use abs and sum to calculate difference measure?

Comment: You can try one of the methods here: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/ . However, finding a threshold value is always going to be hard. You will have to start with a very clear shot boundary and improve the threshold to work with others.